# Upgrade path for indoor sports video from 7D + Samyang 85mm f/1.4 MF lens?

Tags: video, camera, hardware

I regularly shoot 720p/50fps  video at ice skating events with a Canon 7D + Samyang 85mm f/1.4 manual focus lens. I set the ISO at 6400 and with the aperture at 11, I have most of the ice rink in focus.

Unfortunately, light conditions sometimes force me to open up to 4, and manual focus gets really hard to get right on fast-moving ice skaters.

Canon 7D has no continuous autofocus in video mode, so I  thought of switching to an X-mount system with Fujifilm X-E3 and an XF 56mm f/1.2 lens, but did not have a chance to try it out. Is the manual focus easier with an EVF? They seem to have a few modes that help manual focus, but what about the EVF lag?

Any other recommendation? Sony A7S is somewhat pricey, and I am not sure that it can autofocus well enough for my needs either.

I can also switch from 7D to 5DmkII and still shoot at 720p/50fps with an extra sensitivity of a bigger sensor. But this will mean losing some DOF, and I won't have continuous autofocus so what's the point?

Last but not least, is there a system that has fast enough continuous focus to track an ice skater? They move fast, but the background is mostly white and the distance varies between 10 and 40 meters.

Mod's Note: Please keep answers to the video portion of the question. If you want to answer recommendations based on the photo portion, it is covered [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/93847/upgrade-path-for-indoor-sports-photography-from-7d-samyang-85mm-f-1-4-mf-lens).